# UISegmentedControl sticky mode

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

Is it possible to have a `UISegmentedControl` stick when it is selected, rather than just act as a normal button?  In this sense they would be more like a `UISwitch`.

Here is my code:

```
segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",
                         nil]];
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 30);
    [segmentedControl setWidth:40.0 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [segmentedControl setWidth:40.0 forSegmentAtIndex:1];
    [segmentedControl setWidth:40.0 forSegmentAtIndex:2];


    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlValueDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    segmentedControl.momentary = YES;

    self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl;
```

Here is a video of what is happening: https://www.dropbox.com/s/laijgt3zjdaya1z/Segmented.mov?dl=0

Comment: Yes, that is the default mode for a segmented control.

Comment: Please look at the video I added of my issue.

Comment: That's because you set momentary to YES. That's not the default.

Comment: That did it, thank you! Please take your recommendation out of the comments so I can accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A UISegmentedControl "sticks" when it is selected by default. You're getting the behavior you describe because you set the momentary property to YES. The default is NO, so just delete that line.